# react-native AutoPlay on scroll

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, video, expo-av

```
import { ResizeMode, Video } from 'expo-av';
import { ControlsOverLay } from './controlsOverLay';

return (
    <>
      <Video
        ref={ref}
        source={{ uri: item?.videoLink }}
        style={{
          width: props.width,
          // height: 230,
          alignSelf: 'center',
          aspectRatio: 1
        }}
        posterStyle={{
          width: props.width,
          aspectRatio: 1, alignSelf: 'center', resizeMode: ResizeMode.COVER
        }}
        posterSource={{uri:item.thumbLink}}
        usePoster={true}
        // onLoadStart = {()}
        // onError={() => onImageNotFound()}
        shouldPlay={true}
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.COVER}
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={playbackStatus}
      />

      <ControlsOverLay
        isBuffering={playback.isBuffering}
        playerIndex={props.playerIndex}
        visible>
        {playback.isBuffering && <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} />}
        {playback.isLoaded && playback.isPlaying && (
          <PauseIconPressable onPress={() => ref.current.pauseAsync()} />
        )}

        {!playback.isBuffering &&
          playback.isLoaded &&
          !playback.isPlaying &&
          !playback.didJustFinish && (
            <PlayIconPressable onPress={() => ref.current.playAsync()} />
          )}

        {playback.didJustFinish && (
          <ReplayIconPressable
            onPress={() => {
              ref.current.replayAsync();
            }}
          />
        )}
      </ControlsOverLay>
    </>
  );
```

Hello, I want to get the video to autoplay when it is in the center or if its focused. The rest of the video that aren't in the center or focused should be disabled. Right now video is click to play instead of all autoplay. I am using expo-av react-native

Comment: You may find the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) enlightening for this.

Comment: Thank you for the read. I am using FlatList think you can help me with that?